# Magento 2 : Unable to to get custom image url on list.phtml

Tags: product, magento2.3, category-listing

i have created custom image attribute in magento 2 named as **background_image** screenshot below

[image]

i want to show url of background image in my category listing page, i have tried below code but nothing is giving output

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('background_image')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

$_product->getCustomAttribute('background_image');
```

Please help with what i am missing

Comment: In the "Storefront Properties" tab did you set it to "Used in Product Listing" yes?

Comment: yes i have set it